# Can a non dba user create oracle job?

Tags: oracle11g, jobs

Hi i have connected to oracle as a non dba user (ie, it has no 'dba' privilege).I tried to create an oracle JOB with this user.
But I couldn't. Is it possible to do it as a non dba user?
(Also ,before creating the Job i tried to get what's the current maximum id of existing JOBs.That also I couldn't)

Comment: What sort of job are you trying to create?  A `dbms_job` job?  A `dbms_scheduler` job?  What sort of `dbms_scheduler` job?  What, exactly, did you try?  What error(s) did you get?  What do you mean by the "current maximum id of existing jobs"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need DBA privileges to creae a job.

For further details check the Security Model chapter in the Oracle documentation:

[DBMS_JOBS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_job.htm#ARPLS019)

[DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#BABEJGCH)